# Is it possible to have a time interval in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wondering if there is any way to get a time interval for an item in Flutter?

Example:

I have an item where I set a date when this item was last calibrated, and then I want the application to remind me (with either a push message or an email) after a set period of time for the next calibration and so on.

I use `Firestore` for my database.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look to the **`Duration`** Dart's class.

*Docs: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/Duration-class.html*

To give you an idea, fast code example to initialize a span of time:

```dart
const fastestMarathon = Duration(hours: 2, minutes: 3, seconds: 2);
print(fastestMarathon.inDays); // 0
print(fastestMarathon.inHours); // 2
print(fastestMarathon.inMinutes); // 123
print(fastestMarathon.inSeconds); // 7382
print(fastestMarathon.inMilliseconds); // 7382000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the [timeago](https://pub.dev/packages/timeago) package implementation to compare times.

```
dependencies:
  timeago: ^3.3.0
```

You can use time ago for the exact purpose and it is quite beneficial. It has multiple formats and different language support as well.

```
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;

main() {
    final fifteenAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(minutes: 15));

    print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo)); // 15 minutes ago
    print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo, locale: 'en_short')); // 15m
    print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo, locale: 'es')); // hace 15 minutos
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you give me an example on how to implement this? I want to pick a date for my item, and then 12months later I want to get a message. The example on GitHub didn't get me anything.

Comment: You can show the time in UI until the date in which membership ends at with this implementation. or you can place a check if the user didn't buy new membership after 12 months you can prevent user to do something in application which requires membership